# Nextjs API - query parameters are not being passed

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to get a very simple example to work with NextJs API Route where I pass in query parameters in the link.

However, the query parameters are not being passed and are `undefined`

Here's my code:

#### pages/index.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link"
import React from "react"

const Query = () => {
  return (
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: "api/hello",
        query: { text: "world" },
      }}
    >
      Link to api route
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Query
```

#### pages/api/hello.tsx

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"

export default (_: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log("RECEIVED", _.query) // logs as undefined
  const { text } = _.query
  res.status(200).json({ text: `Hello ${text}` })
}
```

The strange thing is, if I type `https://localhost:3000/api/hello?text=world`, the query parameter is being passed and `_.query == 'world'`

Any idea why this happens and how I can resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I just tried on a new app made with [with-typescript example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-typescript), and your code works without having `undefined` when going to the api route through the link.